# How to get rid of nested subscription when searching for names?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I wrote component that looks for github users by login. However this component has nested subscribe blocks. Please help me rewrite this component, using rxjs-operator that dont use nested subscribe blocks.

Here is the [live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-dumb-components-egufjb?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

My humble attempt to solve the problem is in the same place (see commented code).

Here is a basic concept:

```
fromEvent(this.userSearchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup')
  .pipe(
    map((event: any) => event.target.value),
    filter((res: string) => res.trim().length > 2),
    debounceTime(1000),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )
  .subscribe((text: string) => {
    this.isSearching = true;

    this.httpClient
      .get('https://api.github.com/search/users?q=' + text)
      .subscribe(
        (res) => {
          console.log('res', res);
          this.isSearching = false;
          this.apiResponse = res;
        },
        (err) => {
          this.isSearching = false;
          console.log('error', err.error.errors, err.error.message);
        }
      );
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its fairly easy, just `switchMap` from key event to http call and have it as single pipeline

```
fromEvent(this.userSearchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup')
  .pipe(
    map((event: any) => event.target.value),
    filter((res: string) => res.trim().length > 2),
    debounceTime(1000),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap(text=>{
      this.isSearching = true;  
      return this.httpClient.get('https://api.github.com/search/users?q=' + text)
    })
  ).subscribe(res=> {
    console.log('res', res);
    this.isSearching = false;
    this.apiResponse = res;
  },
  (err) => {
    this.isSearching = false;
    console.log('error', err.error.errors, err.error.message);
  }
);
```

As a bonus, http requests are aborted when they are commencing and search term changes in the meantime

https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-dumb-components-mkvbbw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Heck, not only can you get rid of the inner subscriptions, you can get rid of all subscriptions if you want by using the AsyncPipe, and just streaming all the state properties with each change.

```
fromEvent(this.userSearchInput.nativeElement, 'keyup')
  .pipe(
    map((event: any) => event.target.value),
    filter((res: string) => res.trim().length > 2),
    debounceTime(1000),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap((text: string) =>
      this.httpClient.get('https://api.github.com/search/users?q=' + text).pipe(
        map(apiResponse => ({ apiResponse, isSearching: false })),
        catchError((err) => {
          console.log('error', err.error.errors, err.error.message);
          return of({ apiResponse: undefined, isSearching: false });
        });
        startWith({ apiResponse: undefined, isSearching: true })
      )
    ),
    startWith({ apiResponse: undefined, isSearching: false })
  )
```

Everything is same until the *switchMap*.  Every emission inside this switchMap will be an object with the current state of the search.  When the search starts, it will return a state with *isSearching* as `true`.  When the search completes it will return a state with an object result and *isSearching* set to `false`.  An error will clear the results and set searching to false as well.  Feel free to add an error message object.  Finally before any of the happens, the initial state is one with no results and *isSearching* is `false`.

Since there are multiple properties, you can use this in angular by using `ngIf`.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="myObs$ | async as searchState">
  {{searchState.isSearching}}
  {{searchState.apiResponse | json}}
</ng-container>
```